# How to smartly assign the same value to plenty of variables?

Tags: python, variables, namespaces

I need to analyse a huge data.

In which I need to filter with 20 keywords to find out its value by different rules for each keyword. And I need a variable for each keyword to store its accumulative values.

I know I can make a class so that each keyword will have its own variable, but as they have their own rules, things will be clumsy when using class here.

I figured out that make 20 variables for these keywords is a pragmatic plan for this situation.

And the easiest way I've figured out so far is:

```
n1=n2=n3=n4=n5=n6=n7=n8=n9=n10= 0      # omitted n11 to n20
```

I believe there must be a more simple way, like using 're' library or something, but what's it exactly?

Comment: instead of creating the different variable create a dict: so that it useful or create a list

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ, I think this is good idea, it enlightened me. I'll try to figure out another solution.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is *not* to use individual variables `n1`, `n2`, ..., `nN`. Instead, make a list of numbers and access them by index:

```
all_ns = [0 for _ in range(20)] # or '[0] * 20'
```

now `n1` is just `all_ns[0]`. Alternatively, consider a dictionary:

```
all_ns = {'n{0}'.format(i): 0 for i in range(20)}
```

where `n1` is `all_ns['n1']`.

Comment: @Bakuriu that is an option here, but list multiplication can lead to issues with e.g. copying *references* in nested lists, so I tend to prefer list comprehension.

Comment: Yes, but it is perfectly safe whenever you initialize with an immutable object.

Comment: @Bakuriu I accept that - as I say, it's an option in this case - but then I either spend a few lines explaining the potential pitfalls irrelevant to this case, or set up a new question further down the line when the OP multiplies lists with mutable contents. List comprehension avoids the issue entirely. However, I will add a comment providing the option.